# How to create form on frontend

Tags: joomla-3.x, form, fof

I am working on fof 2.4 project.

In that I need to create a form on frontend.

I have seen form in fof 3.0 in contactus sample component.

But my project is in fof 2.4

Any one created form on front end using fof 2.4.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you read through the FOF documentation?

Comment: yes But I didn't get much more @Lodder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit FoF Contactus or To-Do before FoF3 conversion:

### contactus

https://github.com/akeeba/contactus/tree/7f279af5857cf3056c0eb98e1b5c73bb3def8516

### todo

https://github.com/akeeba/todo-fof-example/tree/a364f3a87120cea442e94be529da01b87073e70d

However, I strongly suggest to implement FoF3. The new [scaffolding](https://github.com/akeeba/fof/wiki/Scaffolding) feature is amazing.